# How to connect a web directory on windows explorer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, iis, networking, microsoft-file-explorer

I have an IIS hosted web directory (directory browsing enabled) on my network. It can be opened through the web browser and previews all the file as default.
And i want to link that website as a folder/drive on my windows explorer as i frequently need those files. It doesn't matter if it's read-only.

I tried mapping the URL and tried to add it as a network drive. None of them work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis Only WebDAV on IIS allows you to map the drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the links below about connect a web directory on windows explorer:

[Accessing WebDAV with Windows](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216473357-Accessing-WebDAV-with-Windows)

[Web folders mapping](https://www.element-it.com/OnlineHelpHTTPCommander/Windows/WebFolders.html)